# onClick event in an echo while loop

Tags: javascript, php, while-loop, onclick, echo

I am trying to have an onClick event to open each instance of the edit link that links to the specific ID in my database so that you can just click to open a new window edit what you have to and not have to browse away from the main page.

I can get get the link to work in a regular href and a target blank, but with the onclick event it doesn't appear to work properly and I need to set the parameters for the window. I have searched around and tried many solutions to other similar problems but I just can't figure out a solution. Is this even possible?

Here is the snippet of code I'm working with.

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {       
    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['lname'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['fname'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['activity'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['guests'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['room'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="" onClick="window.open("edit.php?id='.$row['id'].',\'mywindow\')">Edit</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" >Delete</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
```

Any assistance on this would be amazing, thanks in advance.

Comment: The quotes within `window.open(` seem problematic.  This technique of generating `html` is probably the root cause, have you considered separating the `JavaScript` out of the `html`?

Comment: I have tried separating them and just calling them inside the echo but with very little success. For whatever reason it seems to just keep linking back to the page this sits on. Maybe I'm just coding it wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "<td><a href='' onClick=\"window.open('edit.php?id={$row['id']},\'mywindow\'')\">Edit</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id={$row['id']}' >Delete</a></td>";
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We appreciate your contribution, but please note that content in languages other than English is not allowed. See the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information.

Comment: Hi when I try this the a window pops up and the url reads "/edit.php?id=22,'mywindow'" and the content on page simply reads error. I can get it to function if I remove the 'mywindow' part but I then can't use the parameters below.  
      'width=450,height=800,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,statu s=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=no,resizable=no'

Any ideas if I want to add that? Thanks so much! Amazing!

Comment: i'm sorry for that my english is not well so i can't understand what you mean!